# Pine Script - 2 condition long entry (Customized strategy + MACD cross)

Tags: pine-script, indicator

I'm still new to pine script. I am working on a strategy and I want to add MACD cross condition to the `strategy.long` condition.
My strategy is working (Long entry/exit is okay), but I want to add another condition/rule to the long entries that would eliminate some of the bad trades. **Let's say that I want my initial buy/sell strategy to only give "Long" entries when the "MACD" line is above the "Signal" line.** (and if MACD line is below signal line (bearish), I don't want to take any entries)

I already defined the variables for my strategy and MACD lines. but I don't know how I can embed MACD condition/rule to the entry strategy. (`if`, `loop`?)

Right now I have simple entry/exit strategy:

```
strategy.entry("L", strategy.long,1, when=long)

strategy.close("L", when=short)
```

How can I add the MACD cross condition to the entry strategy?

Comment: The strategy.entry will enter long whenever the value of `when` evaluates to `True`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the logical operator `and`.

```
long = ...
MACDAboveSignal = ...

strategy.entry("L", strategy.long,1, when=long and MACDAboveSignal)
```